# What is The logic behind chatting android app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm beginner android programmer

I am going to start project of chatting android app but seems different from what I know but I've tried to search questions that have been asked they only give codes to copy paste, my question is **what do I need to know additionally to create android chatting app ?** Give me the topics no code that will be my job to do , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase or Google Cloud Messaging, Starting with Firebase is a good idea. You need to know to make http resquests "Communications" with server side.

Comment: Thanks but Will I be able to do google cloud in android studio ?

Comment: No, it is done using external server, not on client side, i prefer you start with Firebase because it's very easy.